# Matlab: Fastest way of real time data saving

Tags: matlab, performance, save, real-time

I'm new to matlab and I need some help for a problem I have at a research project at university. I wondering how I can save data in matlab as fast as possible.

I need to save data delivered by a radar for postprocessing. I tried to save it in a matrix using a .mat file. Unfortunately it was too slow, so I lost some data. (The radar has a pretty high data rate.)

Is there a way to do this faster/What is the fastest way to save data in matlab?

I'm pretty in despair. Could you pleease help me?

Here an example of my previous code (which was too slow):

```
...
m = 'Recording.mat';
N = 500;
Data              =   zeros(N,8); 
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Make measurement and save data
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Index = 1;
for Idx = 1:Cfg.NrFrms
    for Tx=1:4
        % Record data for Tx1-Tx4
        Data            =   Brd.BrdGetData();
        % Save Data for the 8 Rx channels
        for Rx=1:8
            m.Data(1:N, Index)          =   Data(:,Rx);
            Index                       =   Index+1;
        end
    end
end
...
```

The data rate is something like I get 
a four 500x8 (complex valued) matrices every 200 milliseconds. 
The data is transfered from the radar to my laptop via USB3.0. My laptop has about 8GB RAM.

Thank you guys
Tiffany

Comment: Please see: [mcve]

Comment: There isn't one fastest way to write data. What is the format of the data? Also what are the constraints? How much data loss is acceptable (do you really need 64 bits of precision)?

Comment: Like the comment above.  It depends.  I had a similar problem and ended up writing data to a binary file during the data trasmission.  Then process it later into a MAT file for post processing.

Comment: how much data? how much processing can you do on the fly? what is the data acquisition rate? do you have access to gpu, multi-core systems etc? what is your RAM?